# UnityScript treat Vector3 array as Collections.Array

Tags: arrays, collections, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am trying to create a mesh from scratch. I tried to use `.Push()` to dynamically increase the size of the vertices array. I also tried

```
m.vertices.size++;
m.vertices[m.vertices.size-1] = heightMapp;
```

to increase the size by hand, but apparently size is not a member and I know `.length` is read-only. So, how do I treat an array as a `Collections.Array` or how do I increase the size manually?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify the size of `Array` (also known as built in array) in `Unityscript`. This is for performance reasons. You can read about it [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Array.html).

`Mesh.vertices` is an Array and as such you can't directly modify it. What you can do is this:

- create a new `built in array` with the new size that you want, in your case it will be `m.vertices.length+1`
- copy the values from `m.vertices` to the new array
- assign to `m.vertices` the values from the new array using `ToBuiltin`

Code bellow:

```
var tmpArray = new Array();

for( var vert in m.vertices )
{
 tmpArray.Push( vert );
}

m.vertices = tmpArray.ToBuiltin(Vector3) as Vector3[];
```

Note: doing this is probably expensive, there's a reason Unity is using built in arrays for the vertices in meshes, so only do this if you have no other choice. Try to add as many vertices as possible in one step and try to avoid adding them one by one.